# Resize image with Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

Reading an 8 bit bmp and resizing (downscaling) it using resize() causes it to change into 24 bit internally. Scale() keeps the depth, but of course does not look as good so I prefer using the slower resize().

After calling resize(), depth() is still reported as 8 bit, however it is not (total colors is over 400.000)

I tried setting depth to 8, but that does not change the output when writing to disk from 24 to 8 bit.
Also tried to write to a blob specifying format (BMP) and 8 bit. That outputs 24 bit also.

Question is how do I retain the same bit depth when using resize?

```
Magick::Image image;
const int depth2 = image.depth(); // 16
image.read("C:\\earth-huge.bmp"); // 8 bit. 64 colors
const int depth = image.depth(); // 8
int colors2 = image.totalColors(); // 64

image.filterType(Magick::FilterTypes::LanczosFilter);
image.resize(Magick::Geometry(1024, 512));

const int depth3 = image.depth(); // 8
int colors = image.totalColors(); // 409246

image.depth(8); // no effect

int colors3 = image.totalColors(); // 409246

image.write("C:\\earth-huge-magick++.bmp"); // outputs 24 bit bmp
```

Comment: `image.quantizeDither(false);
image.quantizeColors(256);
image.quantize();`

Comment: turns out that depth() is always 8 and not 24 for a 24 bit bmp. image.imageInfo() does not return any data. SetImageInfo(imageInfo, 0, exception); on a clone does not set the magick string. What can be missing in my installation or use of classes?

Comment: The number of color increases due to the interpolation done by `resize`. `scale` uses a "simple ratio algorithm" (nearest neighbour), so it can only decrease the number of colors. Also, `depth` refers to a single channel, and a "24 bit BMP" means "8 bit RGB"

Comment: Interpolation gives a better result but if you're not reducing dimension of the image by much, you'll end up with a much bigger image. Therefore I just want to retain original format while using the best possible filter for scaling. Using quantize, I'm able to go back to the original format, however I still need to figure out what it is. I'm trying to read out the channels count but no matter what, I get no imageInfo result!? My thought was to use 2^(depth*channels) for quantizeColors. Can anyone explain how to get the channel count or how to correctly go back to source format after a resize?